# Performance of for/while loop vs foreach loop on List<T>

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

There are plenty of posts about performance of `for` and `foreach` loops on arrays and `IEnumerable`s in general. Unfortunately, they deal mostly with overheads related to `foreach` loop, and I can't find anything clear about their performance on linked lists - or rather `List<T>`.

---

To keep things simple, I'm going to present my question as two assumptions, and ask if they are correct.

## Assumption 1

When I run the following code:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

//(list is filled here)

foreach (Foo f in list)
{
    f.baz();
}
```

loop iterations are going to execute like this:

> 0: You have a pointer to node 0. Call `baz()` on node 0's item. Move pointer to the node after node 0.
>
> 1: You have a pointer to node 1. Call `baz()` on node 1's item. Move pointer to the node after node 1.
>
> 2: You have a pointer to node 2. Call `baz()` on node 2's item. Move pointer to the node after node 2.
>
> ...
>
> n: You have a pointer to node n. Call `baz()` on node n's item. Move pointer to the node after node n.

In other words, the code above has O(n) complexity.

## Assumption 2

When I run the following code:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

//(list is filled here)

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i].baz();
}
```

or the following code:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

//(list is filled here)

int i = 0;
while (i < list.Count)
{
    list[i].baz();
    i++;
}
```

loop iterations are going to execute like this:

> 0: You have a pointer to `list`. Get pointer to node 0 from `list`. Call `baz()` on node 0's item.
>
> 1: You have a pointer to `list`. Get pointer to node 0 from `list`. Move pointer to the node after node 0. Call `baz()` on node 1's item.
>
> 2: You have a pointer to `list`. Get pointer to node 0 from `list`. Move pointer to the node after node 0. Move pointer to the node after node 1. Call `baz()` on node 2's item.
>
> ...
>
> n: You have a pointer to `list`. Get pointer to node 0 from `list`. Move pointer to the node after node 0. Move pointer to the node after node 1. Move pointer to the node after node 2. **[...]** Move pointer to the node after node (n-2). Move pointer to the node after node (n-1). Call `baz()` on node n's item.

In other words, the code above has O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.

---

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: `List` is not a linked list, as you could see from reading the documentation for the type.

Comment: The major assumption you've made that's incorrect is that a linked list and a List<T> are comparable. They are not. One of the significant differences is that elements in linked lists aren't directly accessible, whereas, with List<T>, elements are directly accessible. This leads to your incorrect assumption in Assumption 2. It might help to think of List<T> as in the same category as an array.

Comment: Also, because enumerators can maintain state (of where they are), even a LinkedList enumerator can deliver O(n) when used by foreach (foreach uses enumerators under the covers).

Comment: Have you written any tests to validate? Not sure what you're asking for: our opinions? Or some metrics? If metrics, show us what code you've written and where you're stuck...  :-)

Comment: @hatchet `The List<T> class is the generic equivalent of the ArrayList class.` Gaaaaah. How come I was so ignorant for so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your assumptions are incorrect. The `List<T>` data type is backed by an array not a Linked List. The logic would be

> 0: You have a refrence to list. Get the internal array and directly jump to the 0th index. Call
>   baz() on node 0's item.
>
> 1: You have a refrence to list. Get the internal array and directly jump to the 1st index's offset. Call
>   baz() on node 1's item.
>
> 2: You have a refrence to list. Get the internal array and directly jump to the 2nd index's offset. Call
>   baz() on node 2's item.
>
> ...
>
> n: You have a refrence to list. Get the internal array and directly jump to the nth index's offset. Call
>   baz() on node n's item.

If you where working with a [`LinkedList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) your description would be correct however `LinkedList<T>` does not have a indexer property `[i]` so you would not be able to pass in a index to retrieve like your code example does.

Comment: _"LinkedList<T> does not have a indexer property [i]"_ -- though, a naïve programmer might use `Enumerable.ElementAt()` to retrieve elements by index from a linked list, which of course would be awful in exactly the way the OP is worried about.